# Self-hosted image archive for clients

Tags: web-apps, images, cms, archiving

I work in a small advertising company and for our clients I need a reliable and simple image, or file, hosting service. We do a lot photography for our clients and the images are used in different media and ads, so they need to download the original file from time to time. At the moment we have to locate the file, and send it to them in an email, which is time consuming. This is not meant for client proofing, it's just for ease of access for the clients to download their already approved and bought images.

The requirements are:

- Client login that leads only to their personal files
- Unlimited downloads / uploads
- Single file or group file upload and download
- Searchable image tags

I have looked into different online solutions like Pixieset, but they have too many limitations or are just too complicated for my clients to use. And before anyone says "everybody can use this or that service", my clients are usually the kind that need to call IT-support to locate their mouse pointer, so I need something extremely straightforward.

This is the flow I'm looking for: the clients reaches the site URL, enters their username+password, their images are loaded as thumbnails where they can choose the files they need (search function is required), and once the images are selected there is a big button that packs the images to *.zip and downloads to their computer.

I've been researching about using WordPress, but I'm hoping there is something different and more specialized out there on the world wide web.

(I'm a web designer by trade, so I'm quite capable of setting up different services.)

Comment: My first thought was to subscribe for an imgur account – but I don't know if that covers it all (especially the "zipped group-download"). So instead, I ask annoying questions here – like: Any budget or price limit?

Comment: Maybe you could use ownCloud and find an app for it for your image searching requirement.